# Propose tag synonym [classic-visual-basic] for [vb6]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

As far as I know, the term "classic-visual-basic" means VB6. It only has 8 questions. [vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6) already has another synonym [vb-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-classic).

Just to be clear [vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6) is the correct 'master' tag, [classic-visual-basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classic-visual-basic) should point to it.

---

I was not able to formally suggest this myself since I received this error:

```
Failed to propose synonym:

Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators
```

So I'm posting here instead. Thanks

---

Update: "classic-visual-basic" now has no questions, but making it a pointer to "vb6" would still be useful.

Comment: What about questions about VB5? Are they not "classic-visual-basic"? Shouldn't this be the other way around?

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's a good question. I had always thought the name "Classic VB" specifically to refer to VB6 because it was the last verion before VB.NET came around. But people might include VB5 in the "Classic" moniker. But in any case, the "classic" tags have very little usage compared to VB6 and people who tag their questions that way are going to see a lot less traffic, to their detriment.

Comment: Well, `vb-classic` is already a synonym for `vb6`, so I guess VB5 people are as out of luck here as they are in the real world :). I don't really feel that strongly about it, especially since `classic-visual-basic` has no tag info and only 26 followers.

Comment: Tag has no questions. Is there a way to ping the followers? I would like some of them to weigh in on this proposal.

Comment: @Joshua weirdly it did have some questions this morning - someone must have edited them all?

Comment: For just 8 questions, it is simpler for a user with sufficient reputation to edit the tag from [tag:classic-visual-basic] to [tag:vb6] and then leave the clean-up system to remove the now unused tag.  For a tag with many tens of questions upwards, the work is harder, but just 8 is child's play.  And, unless someone has a list of the questions that were tagged with the classic tag, that information is gone to all except SO insiders (moderators might be able to find out; SO staff presumably could).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Or with some creativity, (archive.org or SEDE) we can dig out those questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53979265/revisions), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53914644/revisions), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53959046/revisions) and we can see the user who did it was likely [Peter Cooper Jr.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65839/peter-cooper-jr)

Comment: @HereticMonkey with only 39 questions total [vb5] is dead enough we don't really need to give it much concern.

Comment: OK — I'll bite.  How did this make it back to the "Hot Meta Posts" list a day or two after the tag died?  It hasn't even been controversial! (And no, it wasn't me who did the editing — I described the reality; I didn't bring it into being).  It was surprising when it first appeared; it is more than surprising that it has reappeared.  I believe there's a glitch in an algorithm somewhere.  It hasn't even got many views!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler as the OP even though I am sort of pleased it is getting attention... I agree with you, its a pretty trivial issue.... ;)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually though, the tag itself is still in existence, just has no questions

Comment: You get the same '0 questions asked' page from searching for `[visual-maelstrom-artistry]` as you do for `[classic-visual-basic]`.  (Whether that's a bug or not is a separate debate — I'd argue that it would be better to say that the tag doesn't exist than to make it appear that it does but it is unused.)  If you use the tags section on the LHS of the SO page, you can search for `classic-visual-basic` and it doesn't appear.  So the tag doesn't currently exist.  If you tried to add it to a question, you'd be asked whether you really want to create the tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks that was not clear at all!

Comment: Can we rather synomym-ise `[vb6]` as `[hell]`?

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see the purpose for this tag. Remember, tags are not created "just to be there", but to actually be used in the site's business process.

What role do synonyms play here?

When you start typing a tag name, you're presented by tags which (either themselves of any of thgeir synonyms) match the typed substring.

E.g. as of this writing, when I type in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, I'm getting:

- `visual-` => c#, vba, visual studio, a few unrelated tags.
- `visual-ba` => only vba left. So I see there are no relevant tags for full-fledged VB versions with a full name.
- `vb` => vb.net, vba, excel-vba, access-vba etc. Here, that's what the site uses for VB flavors!
- `vb-c` => vb6 (via vb-classic), vbc, and an unrelated tag. So, I see that "vb-classic" suggests vb6 specifically here, so if I'm interested in vb5, I'll type "vb5" and for vb6, I'll choose the suggested vb6.

The system works as it is, so I don't see how adding another synonym will improve anything.

Comment: If you are saying to just delete it instead, that's fine with me!

Comment: @DaveInCaz [tag:classic-visual-basic] doesn't exist currently, so there's nothing to delete :-)